# how to get value from html "select" list for a switch statement in php

Tags: php

What i would like to do is create a select list the user can chose a capital city from and based on there selection, display the related state name. So if user chooses Atlanta, Georgia is displayed via button click.

**HTML**

```
<select>
  <option value="atlanta">Atlanta</option>
  <option value="raleigh">Raleigh</option>
  <option value="phoenix">Phoenix</option>
  <option value="austin">Austin</option>
</select>
<button type="button" value="city_submit" 
onclick="--call the php function--">Show State</button>
```

**PHP**

```
        <?php
        function state_cap(){
            $user_city = "get the value from the select list";
            switch ($user_city) {
                 case "atlanta":
                     echo "Georgia";
                     break;
                 case "raleigh":
                     echo "North Carolina";
                     break;
                 case "phoenix":
                     echo "Arizona";
                     break;
                case "austin":
                    echo "Texas";
                    break;
            }
        }
        ?>
```

how do i get the button to call the php function?

then how do i set the variable to the option value selected?

Comment: Where are your form tags? <--- Forget that, I just saw your onclick part... You can't use an onclick event on PHP, it is for JavaScript. PHP is server side. I suggest you learn the basics first.

Comment: That's not how PHP works. It's a server-side language. You can't directly interact with it in client-side code like this. You need to read about AJAX.

Comment: here are my exact instructions.......Use a switch statement to determine which state someone lives in based on the capital city... should i use javascript then? im suppose to be using php

Comment: @kronis72 If you want to use PHP or need to use it, look in to forms with PHP.

Comment: @script47 while my example code and question may not use the correct terms or methods, i didnt know how else to get my point across about what i was trying to do. but burning crystals answer is what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should enclose your `<select>` and submit `<button>` with `<form>` tags with the `action` attribute pointed to your function script. (notice the `<button>`'s `type` attribute)

index.html

```
<form action="function.php" method="post">
<select name="user_city">
  <option value="atlanta">Atlanta</option>
  <option value="raleigh">Raleigh</option>
  <option value="phoenix">Phoenix</option>
  <option value="austin">Austin</option>
</select>
<button type="submit" value="city_submit">Show State</button>
</form>
```

function.php

```
    <?php

    if (isset($_POST['user_city'])) {
        state_cap(strtolower($_POST['user_city']));
    }

    function state_cap($user_city){
        switch ($user_city) {
             case "atlanta":
                 echo "Georgia";
                 break;
             case "raleigh":
                 echo "North Carolina";
                 break;
             case "phoenix":
                 echo "Arizona";
                 break;
            case "austin":
                echo "Texas";
                break;
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Considering the OP's knowledge you should probably expand on what you  said and maybe provide some resources for them to read up on.

Comment: thank you, I didnt know exactly how to ask about what I was wanting to do, but this is the solution i was looking for thanks.

Comment: @kronis72 glad i could help. here's an interesting topic from the php manual about php and forms if you want to know more. http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php

Answer (score 0):

onclick="--call the php function--"

You can do it like that only with javascript. You can't call PHP function. What you need to do is just go through to another page and retrieve it through $_GET or $_POST.